# Polynomial With Nonnegative Coefficients

Tags: combinatorics

Prove that 
$\sum_{\ell=0}^{k}\binom{k}{\ell}\binom{n+d-\ell}{d}$
has nonnegative coefficients when expanded in term of $n$ for any $k$ and $d$ being integers with $0\le k\le d$.

This problem comes from a pdf of additional problems by Stanley for his famous book on Enumerative Combinatorics. I have tried any number of techniques and nothing appears to work, in particular I am generally unfamiliar with what ideas one can use to show that a polynomial have nonnegative coefficients in general other than explicitly evaluating it.

Comment: what is the question here?

Comment: The question is asking to prove the original claim.